# How to auto integrate changes to other branches

Tags: perforce

I have an auto integrate trigger set up that can integrate between about 15 branches, all within the same product. My depot is set up like

```
//Product/dev/main/...
//Product/dev/v1.0/...
//Product/releases/v1.0.0/...
//Product/releases/v1.1.0/...
```

etc. That is easy enough to integrate between. My trigger does a search and replace on these depot paths to integrate from one to the other. It gets these paths via subtasks in Jira. Now other projects want the same thing. The problem is not all projects follow the same structure. Some are more like

```
//ProductB/SubProject/dev/main/...
//ProductB/SubProject/dev/v1.0/...
//ProductB/releases/v1.0.0/...
//ProductB/releases/v1.1.0/...
```

So I can't use the same search and replace method, because it may be different between projects. I was hoping someone might have a integrate trick I could use. Branchspecs don't appeal to me because we have over 18 products, with some products having over 15 branches. So if I create a new branch for a product, I have to create 16 branchspecs. Doable, but painful.

Comment: Branches should be done in some kind of hierarchy, so you wouldn't need a spider web of branch specs.  You should just need `n - 1` specs, where `n` is the number of branches.

Comment: Not true. If I have  branches 1,2,3 I have 3 specs 1->2,1->3,2-3 Then if I add branch 4, I gain 3 more, 1->4,2->4,3->4 for a total of 6, add another branch, 1->5,2->5,3->5,4->5 for a total of 10. So it's not n-1

Comment: That is why I said hierarchy.  If all your branches are peers, you will quickly run into a lot of problems.  Besides, all your branches aren't peers because version 2.0 of your product is not the same as version 1.0.

Comment: Due to the size of my product, they may not be peers, but new branches are mostly just the addition of features. So older bug fixes on 15 year old code usually has to go to all branches. Someday we'll get all our customers to upgrade, but until then, we still have to update old branches.

Comment: Well, then you brought this headache on yourself with that branching scheme.  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, all `//productB` branches have a common ancestor, right?
I think you could programmatically call `p4 filelog -i` and parse the output to see where it belongs to.

> The -i flag includes inherited file history. If a file was created by
>           branching (using 'p4 integrate'), filelog lists the revisions of the
>           file's ancestors up to the branch points that led to the specified
>           revision.  File history inherited by renaming (using 'p4 move') is
>           always displayed regardless of whether -i is specified.

Answer (score 0):

Capturing this high level relationship (merge source and target) has to be captured either in a branch spec or a configuration file of some sort.

Once the new *streams* feature is available later this year, the parent/child relationship between two codelines will be captured directly in Perforce, making an automatic merge script much easier to write.

Comment: I agree, streams would work, but I don't have access to those yet